# Split the Form Label code and Form Value code in Symfony view

Tags: php, forms, symfony

**StudentType.php**

```
$builder->add('internalId', null, array(
    'label' => "Student ID",
    'attr' => array('class' => 'studentInternalId', 'size' => 10, 'readonly' => 'readonly', 'placeholder' => 'Auto-generated', 'style' => 'width: 80px;', 'tabindex' => '-1', 'style' => 'pointer-events:none; opacity: 0.8; cursor: not-allowed')
));
```

**index.html.twig**

```
{{ form_row(contractStudent.student.internalId) }}
```

**Output :**

```
Label : InputField
```

Can i write separate code for Label and a separate code for value to display in the index.html.twig file.?

i want to create a link for value when the user clicks on the link I will take the user to another page. for that, I need that field value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to render only the field :

```
{{ form_widget(form.name) }}
```

for the label :

```
{{ form_label(form.name) }}
```